# How do i modify all the contents of an array at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

code:

```
Char_Data[] char_Data = new Char_Data[]
{
 Char_Data.CreateCharacter(StatCard_Base.ReturnCardByName<StatCard_Character>("hank"),
 Char_Data.CreateCharacter(StatCard_Base.ReturnCardByName<StatCard_Character>("jeb"),
 Char_Data.CreateCharacter(StatCard_Base.ReturnCardByName<StatCard_Character>("tricky")
};

char_Data[0].GiveXP(XP.Types.Unarmed, 9000000);
char_Data[0].GiveXP(XP.Types.Melee, 9000000);
char_Data[0].GiveXP(XP.Types.Ranged, 9000000);
char_Data[0].GiveXP(XP.Types.Acrobatic, 9000000);
char_Data[0].myCash = 999999999;

char_Data[1].GiveXP(XP.Types.Unarmed, 9000000);
char_Data[1].GiveXP(XP.Types.Melee, 9000000);
char_Data[1].GiveXP(XP.Types.Ranged, 9000000);
char_Data[1].GiveXP(XP.Types.Acrobatic, 9000000);
char_Data[1].myCash = 999999999;

char_Data[2].GiveXP(XP.Types.Unarmed, 9000000);
char_Data[2].GiveXP(XP.Types.Melee, 9000000);
char_Data[2].GiveXP(XP.Types.Ranged, 9000000);
char_Data[2].GiveXP(XP.Types.Acrobatic, 9000000);
char_Data[2].myCash = 999999999;
```

Instead of copy pasting the entire thing multiple times, how can I do this to them all at once? I've tried

```
char_Data[].myCash=99;
```

and

```
char_Data.myCash=99;
```

and I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can loop over the array.

Comment: Depending on how you store these individual characters maybe you should just implement a method that simply sets all these values so you don't have to do set them one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use a for loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < char_Data.Length; i++) {
    char_Data[i].GiveXP(XP.Types.Unarmed, 9000000);
    char_Data[i].GiveXP(XP.Types.Melee, 9000000);
    char_Data[i].GiveXP(XP.Types.Ranged, 9000000);
    char_Data[i].GiveXP(XP.Types.Acrobatic, 9000000);
    char_Data[i].myCash = 999999999;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to loop until `i < char_Data.Length` instead of hard-coding the number of items.

Comment: Or `foreach`? ;)